# How to install Xcode on Windows 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi I've recently become interested in developing applications for iOS. I've taken classes in Objective-C before, and we've always used Xcode to build and run our programs. I am a Windows user at home, and I'm not interested in buying a Macintosh. Is there any way to install Xcode on a Windows 8 PC? Any help is appreciated, thanks. :D

Comment: you would probably have to run osx in virtual box and install it on that, never tried before but prob can find out how if you google around

Comment: At least try to google next time. http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-install-xcode-5-on-windows-7-windows-8-8-1-ios-sdk

Comment: No there is absolutely no (Official) way that you can install the `xcode IDE` on a `Windows 8`

Answer (score 7):

You can not install xcode on windows 8 because it requires MAC OS, and Windows and MAC are two different operating system.

To install xcode you have to make VM workstation on your machine and make MAC OS on that or you have to purchase a MAC Machine.

You can also have dual boot on your machine, Keep in mind that dual boot or MAC OS on VM Workstation did not support sound, wifi and some other resources.

Comment: Except Apple doesn't allow OS X to be run on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: this is just an alternative way, in case if someone can't purchase a MacBook

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you cannot install Xcode on a Windows PC - just like you cannot install Visual Studio and develop for Windows on a Mac.
The only way I can think of, is if you install MacOS in a Virtual Machine (e.g. http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using a virtual machine. I just wanted to make sure there was no other, better way to use Xcode on Windows.

Comment: As rmaddy stated, Apple does not allow their OS running on non-Apple devices. Gladly there are (not so legal) ways to install it nonetheless ;)

Comment: It is very painful to develop in a virtual machine as hardware accelerated graphics is not possible with this setup. MacOS and Xcode will lag. And is has gotten worse with recent MacOS updates (as of 2016). I would not recommend anybody to develop this way. I am afraid you will have to buy a Mac computer.